# why the gl_ClipDistance[] doesn't work?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I just can't understand why the gl_ClipDistance doesn't work. The result is the same as I didn't set the gl_ClipDistance.

I had set glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0+2) by application.

the vertex shader is like this:

```
#version 410

uniform mat4    mvpMatrix;
//.......some other uniforms here
in vec2 vVertex;
uniform vec4 clip_plane=vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,0.85);
uniform vec4 clip_sphere=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0);

void main(void) 
    { 
    //........some other code,include vec2 worldPos
    vec4 worldPosition=vec4(worldPos.x,height,worldPos.y,1.0);
    gl_ClipDistance[0]=dot(worldPosition,clip_plane);
    gl_ClipDistance[1]=length(worldPosition.xyz/worldPosition.w-clip_sphere.xyz)-clip_sphere.w;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;
    }
```

PS:after told by good men, I had known that " glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0+2) " is not right. so I set "glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0) ;glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE1) ;",but it still didn't work.

Then,I tried to only set "glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0)"and"gl_ClipDistance[0]=-1.0" ,but what make me confused is that my model just still stay there,didn't disappear.

Anybody know how this happen?

Comment: so have you figured it out? I'm having exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

> I had set `glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0+2)` by application.

But not `GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0` and `GL_CLIP_DISTANCE1`.

From [`gl_ClipDistance`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_ClipDistance.xhtml):

> Values written into `gl_ClipDistance` planes that are not enabled have no effect.

Enable `GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0` and `GL_CLIP_DISTANCE1` if you intend to write to `gl_ClipDistance[0]` and `gl_ClipDistance[1]`.

Comment: I set like this now glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
 glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE1);

Answer (score 1):

#### You are invoking undefined behavior here.

`GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0 + 2` is actually the *third* clip distance in `gl_PerVertex.gl_ClipDistance [...]`.

> ### Name
>
> > **[`gl_ClipDistance`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/gl_ClipDistance.xml)** — provides a forward-compatible mechanism for vertex clipping
>
> ### Description
>
> > [...]
> >
> > The number of varying components consumed by `gl_ClipDistance` will match the size of the array, no matter how many planes are enabled. ***The shader must also set all values in `gl_ClipDistance` that have been enabled via the OpenGL API, or results are undefined.*** Values written into `gl_ClipDistance` planes that are not enabled have no effect.

Since you have enabled clipping against `gl_ClipDistance [2]` but have not written anything to it, your per-vertex output is actually only an array of **2** clip distances, and the third is undefined. Clipping against something that is undefined will produce unpredictable behavior.

There is a requirement that the array be sized to include the highest enabled clip plane. That means if you enable `GL_CLIP_DISTANCE2`, `gl_ClipDistance []` needs to have a size of **3**. GLSL automatically resizes that array if you index it using a constant integer expression (as you have done when you use **0** and **1**), but it only resizes it to **2**, not **3**.